# How Tasklets works?

Tags: linux

Does interrupts are disabled while tasklets are being processed since they should run in interrupt context.If they are disbled while a tasklet is being processed then what is the point of calling them bottom halve mechanism since it is same case as top of where the interrupts are disabled.
Or is it like tasklets will be useful only on multi processor system where the interrupts are generated on one processor and the corresponding tasklet is scheduled on another processor with interrupts being disbled on another processor when the tasklet is running.
Please clarify.

Comment: Googling on tasklet give me first http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-5 which seems to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Linux divides interrupt processing in two parts:

- First, you handle the interrupt request (IRQ) in as simple a manner as possible, doing as little as you can, and scheduling a softirq/tasklet to do the heavier part of the processing.
- Then, the softirq/tasklet gets scheduled, and the heavy processing starts.

The contexts in Linux are:

- **NMI context**
- **hardirq context**: the first part of interrupt processing above.
- **softirq context**: the second part of interrupt processing above.
- **interrupt context**: any of the above.
- **process/user context**: running on behalf of a process, e.g: due to a syscall. The opposite of interrupt context.
- **atomic context**: interrupt context, or in process context in a section of code that must be atomic (cannot be interrupted), e.g: because we have taken a spinlock.

Interrupts are not disabled while running a tasklet. Further invocations of the same tasklet are.